# Textmate Regex Issue

Tags: regex, textmate

I have a very large .CSV document with text I need removing. The data looks like this

```
774431994&amp;images=774431994,774431996,774431998,774432000,774432003,774432006,774432009&amp;formats=0,0,0,0,0 /1/6/9/5/2/6/8/webimg/774431994

774431996&amp;images=774431994,774431996,774431998,774432000,774432003,774432006,774432009&amp;formats=0,0,0,0,0 /1/6/9/5/2/6/8/webimg/774431996

774431998&amp;images=774431994,774431996,774431998,774432000,774432003,774432006,774432009&amp;formats=0,0,0,0,0 /1/6/9/5/2/6/8/webimg/774431998

774432000&amp;images=774431994,774431996,774431998,774432000,774432003,774432006,774432009&amp;formats=0,0,0,0,0 /1/6/9/5/2/6/8/webimg/774432000

774432003&amp;images=774431994,774431996,774431998,774432000,774432003,774432006,774432009&amp;formats=0,0,0,0,0 /1/6/9/5/2/6/8/webimg/774432003                

774432006&amp;images=774431994,774431996,774431998,774432000,774432003,774432006,774432009&amp;formats=0,0,0,0,0 /1/6/9/5/2/6/8/webimg/774432006

774432009&amp;images=774431994,774431996,774431998,774432000,774432003,774432006,774432009&amp;formats=0,0,0,0,0 /1/6/9/5/2/6/8/webimg/774432009
```

I'm using the following Regex which is working on http://regexr.com/3a6oa

```
/.{128}(?=webimg).{10}/g
```

It just doesn't seem to work with Textmate Search. Does anyone know why? I need to select all of this junk and replace it with nothing, the numbers are unique each time.

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Why are you using a lookahead in your pattern? Just use: `/.{128}webimg.{10}/g`
- Why are you using Textmate search at all? I'd need to know more context of the problem to say for sure, but I bet a simple `sed` command could just be used instead:

`sed -i "webimg/d" ./filename.csv`

Comment: Its a long story but short version... I'm needing to create an import for Shopify, I'd exported from eBay but the product descriptions contain nasty inline eBay template HTML which I needed to remove.(as it was breaking my CSV) I'm not familiar with Regex but found this the only way to remove dynamic HTML (the product images). I used your Regex and it worked just fine. Thanks very much for taking the time to answer!